# Where can you find old versions of Android NDK?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

Using this wiki, anyone can easily get any version of android-ndk

http://www.wikihow.com/Download-Previous-Android-NDK

Comment: Is this a question , are you asking ? Or just sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

We maintain a list of older downloads here: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki